# If two distinct primes divides the same number, will their product divide this too?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If two distinct primes p,q divides a number z, will their product $pq$ also divide z, that is $pq|z$? And how can I prove this. Thanks,

Comment: Isn't this a more or less immediate consequence of the unique factorization theorem (fundamental theorem of arithmetic)?

Comment: Use the Fundamental Theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: If you don't want to go all the way to the fundamental theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma might help.

Comment: Euclids lemma did the job, thanks everyone.

Comment: $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)=1$ means in your setup, that $a\nmid b$ and $b\nmid a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $p\mid z\implies z=p\cdot k$ for some integer $k$. At the same time, Eucklid's Lemma establishes that $$q\mid z\iff q\mid p\cdot k\implies q\mid p\;\text{ or/and }\;q\mid k$$ Observe that $q\mid p$ is nonsense, since both $p$ and $q$ are primes. Therefore $q\mid k\implies k=q\cdot m$ for some integer $m$. But then $z=p\cdot k=p\cdot q\cdot m\implies pq\mid z$.